# Disable submit input field until all required fields and checkboxes are empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple web page to get input data:

Input form:

```
const Step1 = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const classes = useStyles();
  const { actions, state } = useStateMachine({ updateAction });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    actions.updateAction(data);
    props.history.push("./step2");
  };
  var grid_data=data.map(function(row){return FormRow(row);})
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h2>Enter your data</h2>
      {grid_data}

      <FormControlLabel
        control={<WhiteCheckbox  name="Usage_terms" />}
        label="I accept Terms of Usage"
        style={{ margin: "auto", marginLeft:-10}}
      />
      <input type="submit" style={{width: "460px", backgroundColor: "green", marginTop:5 }}  />
    </form>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Step1);
```

Where grid data is created from a special function and json-file "data":

```
function FormRow( {row_label, row_info, row_mes_unit} ) {
  const row_classes=useStyles()
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  return (  <React.Fragment>
          <Grid item container xs alignItems="flex-end" direction="row">
            <Grid item xs>
            <input type="number" style={{width: "410px", height:"35px"}} placeholder={row_label} {...register(row_label, {required: true, max: 100, min: 0, maxLength: 100})} />
            </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={2} justify="flex-end" >
            <HtmlTooltip
              title={ 
                    <React.Fragment>
                    <Typography color="inherit">Help</Typography>
                    <p><b>{"Info:"}</b> {row_info} </p>
                    <p><b>{"Mes. Unit:"}</b> {row_mes_unit}</p>
                    
                     </React.Fragment>
              } 
            >
            <Button className={row_classes.button}     style={{
        backgroundColor: "inherit",
        borderRadius: 5,
    }}>
                <HelpOutlineIcon className={classNames(row_classes.rightIcon, row_classes.iconSmall)}  />
            </Button>
            </HtmlTooltip>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>   
  );
```

**The question is** how to disable submit input until all requested fields and checkbox are filled in?

Comment: by default keep it disabled, track all the field values with some flag (a boolean) or check if all properties (usually form values) as objects are not empty ..

Comment: @Codenewbie, then the question is how to check if all the inputs are not empty? I'm really a newbie in javascript, sorry

Comment: not necessarily it to be as it can be understood the same way, I suggest to have a track of all fields in state, defaulting to empty or null values depending upon you choose them to be and have a check on all values of state to enable button

Comment: there would be much better ways to do but i have a small example (though not recommended as state may be contain fields other than form values too ... ) [just for an idea](https://codepen.io/codeITNewbie/pen/rNmmQoE?editors=0010)

Comment: @Codenewbie, can you please help with getting values from the input states? I'm not sure how to implement it, and how conduct this check? on every render?

Comment: can you add a codesandbox or codepen of working sample ...

Comment: @Codenewbie, sorry for the late response, here is the link for the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-kalam-v1lpg